# llvm-sys - Didn't find usable system wide LLVM. But llvm-config is installed

Tags: rust, llvm

I have built llvm-13.0.1 from source using Visual Studio 17 2022 on Windows 11. When attempting to build llvm-sys (through external crate llvm-ir). It fails, saying:

```
error: No suitable version of LLVM was found system-wide or pointed to by LLVM_SYS_130_PREFIX.
```

I know llvm-config exists because I can use it from the command line, and it returns the correct version. I don't understand why this doesn't work. This might be a stupid question but I am really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this problem, trying to use llvm-sys on Windows. Here are some mistakes that I did that made it fail to compile just like yours.

## Installation Prefix

Make sure that your LLVM installation path doesn't have any whitespace.

Mine was `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM`, which was their default install prefix. The whitespace in the installation path causes some errors when using it with **llvm-sys**. Later, I changed it to `C:\LLVM` and it worked.

## Set Environment Variable

Set Environment Variable `LLVM_SYS_<version>_PREFIX` to the installed LLVM folder.

### From CMD For LLVM-13.0.1

```
setx LLVM_SYS_130_PREFIX "<PATH TO LLVM WITHOUT WHITESPACE>" /M
```

Make sure that the variable is registered by using `echo` command

```
echo %LLVM_SYS_130_PREFIX%
```

It should output your registered path, not `%LLVM_SYS_130_PREFIX%`.
If it doesn’t output your path, restart the computer and try again and it should be working.

Now you should be good to go .....

Hope this helps :)